# InfoPath richtextbox border issue

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010

I have add hyperlink in between the text dynamically as a label in SharePoint InfoPath 2010. I was able to add it by using richtextbox control by making it readonly.. Everything working fine but mouseover and focus showing unwanted border on the richtextbox.. How can we remove this border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot easily remove the mouseover border in InfoPath 2010. You could adding a Content Editor Web Part to your input page and putting some JavaScript in there to override the default InfoPath mouseover functionality, but you're going to run into a significant number of problems. Your best alternative is to put your hyperlink in a Section and attach your hide/show rules to the Section.